# How can i in a smart way sort my data into different bins

Tags: python, pandas, bins

Hello i am using pandas to import data from two excel files, an example of the data contained in one of the files is shown below. Basically i am trying to find the timestamps which are identical in the two files and then sort e.g the data from the "Power" column which corresponds to the same timestamp from the two files into some bins. The bins in this example are from 0-50, 50-100 and so on with intervals of 50 up to e.g. 1000

```
1.  Location    UnitName    Timestamp           Power        Windspeed   Yaw
2.  Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 00:00:00 7,563641548  3,957911002 280,5478821     
3.  Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 00:20:00 60,73444748  4,24157236  280,4075012
4.  Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 00:30:00 63,15441132  4,241089859 280,3903809
5.  Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 00:40:00 59,09280396  4,38904965  280,4152527
6.  Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 00:50:00 69,26197052  4,374599175 280,3750916
7.  Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 01:00:00 101,0624237  5,343887005 280,5173035
8.  Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 01:10:00 122,7936935  5,183885235 280,4681702
9.  Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 01:20:00 86,57110596  5,046733923 280,3834534     
10. Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 01:40:00 16,74042702  3,024427626 280,1408386
11. Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 01:50:00 12,5870142   2,931351769 280,1185913
12. Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 02:00:00 -1,029753685 3,116549245 279,9686279
13. Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 02:10:00 13,35998058  3,448055706 279,8687134
14. Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 02:20:00 17,42461395  2,943588415 280,1383057
15. Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 02:30:00 -9,614940643 2,744164819 280,6514893   
16. Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 02:50:00 -11,01966286 3,554833538 283,1451416
17. Bull Creek  F10         01/11/2014 03:00:00 -4,383010387 4,279259377 283,3281555
```

I am wondering if there is a more intelligent way to do this, than what i have worked out so far, since the size of the bins and max value could change. But this is the code i have which works but not very smart.

```
import pandas as pd

fileREF = 'FilterDataREF.xlsx'

dataREF = pd.read_excel(fileREF, sheetname='Sheet1')

filePCU = 'FilterDataPCU.xlsx'

dataPCU = pd.read_excel(filePCU, sheetname='Ark1')

dateREF = dataREF['Timestamp']
datePCU = dataPCU['Timestamp']


n = 50
PowerLim = 1500
nBins = PowerLim/n
bins = range(0, PowerLim+1, n)

for i in range(len(dataREF)):
    for j in range(len(dataPCU)):
        if dataREF['Timestamp'][i] == dataPCU['Timestamp'][j] and 
        dataREF['Power'][i] > 0 and dataPCU['Power'][j] > 0:
         data_common = [dataREF.loc[i], dataPCU.loc[j]]

         data_power = [data_common[0][3], data_common[1][3]]
         power_dif = data_common[1][3]-data_common[0][3]

         power_REF = data_power[:][0]
         power_PCU = data_power[:][1]

         bin1 = power_REF[power_REF < 50]
         bin2 = power_REF[power_REF > 50 and power_REF < 100]
         bin3 = power_REF[power_REF > 100 and power_REF < 150]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .cut function:

```
data_common['bin'] = pd.cut(data_common['power_REF'],bins=(0,max(data_common['power_REF'])+50,50),labels=range(0,max(data_common['powerREF'])+50,50))
```

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers not str using the code that you wrote. but thank you for finding the cut function i guess i will try to figure out how to adapt that to my problem

Comment: Its my bad, i thought data_common is a dataframe and not a list. 
Why dont you combine the two dataframes and then run the bins on the power column? If its always the same bins it wouldnt make a difference, and after words you can slice it by the timestaps

Comment: Yeah that was my thought excatly aswell should be possible, so i will try that thank you :)